# Querying based on proximity of an integer in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app where the users all have a score they have achieved.  I want to show the user a list of other users who's have the closest scores to their own.  I want this to be in order of +/- from the users score.  I realize I am explaining this poorly, so how about an example?

```
current_user.score = 825

user1.score = 827
user2.score = 818
user3.score = 824
user4.score = 887
```

So when I do this query:

```
User.where("score NEAR ?", current_user.score).order("proximity ASC") # I'm just making this up.
```

It returns the results in this order:

- user3
- user1
- user2
- user4

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.find(:all, :order => "ABS(score - #{current_user.score}) DESC")
```

or, if you want to keep the values:

```
User.find(:all,
          :select => "*, ABS(score - #{current_user.score}) as diff",
          :order => 'diff DESC')
```

of course you should sanitize current_user.score.

Answer (score 3):

```
User.where(:score => (current_user.score - offset)..(current_user.score + offset))
```

Another way:

```
# 5 higher scores higher than the user's 
User.where("score >= ? AND id != ?", current_user.score, current_user.id).order("score ASC").limit(5)
# 5 scores lower than the user's
User.where("score <= ? AND id != ?", current_user.score, current_user.id).order("score DESC").limit(5)
```

Comment: in the first method, where does the offset come from? In the second method it seems it only returns users who's score is higher than the current users.

Comment: Offset is another variable in your program. See the edited answer as my response to your second question.